# Getting the characters within square brackets in a python string

Tags: python, string, praw

I'm attempting to create a reddit bot that downloads all new images from a subreddit, I've already gotten the downloading part done, but what I'm now trying to do is group those images into specific directories based on a specific set of strings in the title. Here's an example of a title: "Hello [1234x1234]"

I only want the characters within the square brackets, whatever they are. How would I go about this?

Comment: Have a look at the `re` module.

Comment: You probably want the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library for extracting information from strings using regular expressions.

Comment: I had a look through the documentation and it's quite confusing. Could you direct me more specifically at the parts that apply to my scenario?

Comment: I don't know why they are suggesting regex when a simple split would work. If `s` is your input string, `"1234x1234"` is given by `s.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]`.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. Last question, how exactly does the [1] and [0] work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` to get only `1234x1234`

`\[` and `\]` matches the opening and closing square brackets.
`.+?` matches one or more characters except a newline and stops as soon as it finds the closing square bracket.
`(` and `)` will capture the characters matched by `.+?`

```py
import re


title = "Hello [1234x1234]"
match = re.search(r"\[(.+?)\]", title)

if match:
    target = match.group(1)
    print(target)
```

Output:

```
1234x1234
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I was given a more simple method by another user